# Breadcrumb for Homepage/Landing

Tags: breadcrumbs, homepage

The site I'm making - and as a lot others do - has a unique homepage, which is more like an index to the site than a part of it; imagine an exclusive (and loud) layout scheme, elements, content, all of which further links to the content part on my site.

Since the homepage makes itself so evident, is there a need to sacrifice pixels and visual flow for a strip of breadcrumb that is only gonna say "Home"?

Comment: There is a [similar question on breadcrumbs for homepage here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21662/should-home-be-included-in-website-breadcrumbs) although that question is whether or not to *link to* the Home from the breadcrumb rather than whether it should even be present on the homepage at all.

Comment: [Web Usability Blog](http://webusability-blog.com/breadcrumb-7-tips/) recommends against including a breadcrumb on the homepage.

Comment: A breadcrumb serves no purpose on the home page.

Answer (score 4):

I would tend to mostly agree with most who have already commented on your question in that breadcrumbs serve no purpose on the homepage.

Besides the resource already mentioned by @Brian above, [baekdal.com](http://www.baekdal.com/insights/breadcrumbguidelines) includes a relevant point:

> Front page breadcrumbs are often a mistake because it only contains "Home" - it is not even linked. Your visitors will most likely be confused about this single word, and not get the idea before they visit a sub page.

Breadcrumbs are a trail back to the homepage, and since you're already there (and you've mentioned it's obvious where you are), it would just be another redundant link to the same page -- taking up unnecessary space.

<sub>Note: The one case you could possibly argue for (although not a very good point) is that all sub-pages may have breadcrumbs and thus the layout could be considered inconsistent by not having the same bar on the homepage.</sub>